# Section `text` will not fit after upgrading `arm-none-eabi-gcc`

Tags: gcc, arm, newlib, libopencm3

I have an [open source micromouse robot project](https://github.com/Bulebots/bulebule). For easier compilation, I use containers (both Podman and Docker should be fine):

```
make image
make libopencm3
make
```

This works just fine and generates a `main.elf` file about 874 kB in size. But that is as long as I fix the `arm-none-eabi-gcc-cs` to `7.4.0` in the Dockerfile.

If I remove the specific version or set it to `9.2.0`, then I get the following error:

```
$ make
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: main.elf section `.text' will not fit in region `rom'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: region `rom' overflowed by 5288 bytes
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [opencm3/libopencm3.rules.mk:204: main.elf] Error 1
```

What could have changed between those versions?

If I add this line to my Makefile:

```
LDFLAGS         += -specs=nano.specs
```

Then it compiles just fine with version `9.2.0` and generates a `main.elf` file about 885 kB in size. But I wonder if the performance would be the same (or equivalent) as before.

### Update

I am expecting some performance differences, of course, just like I was expecting some differences in the binary size. But I was wondering if I could expect a higher than 20% difference in performance (specially if it could be now 20% slower).

The new binary is less than 2% bigger, and I would consider this to be "the same" as before. :-D

Comment: The performance is expected to change simply due to using different gcc versions.  (dont assume for the better).  You have to just test it for functionality and performance since you changed compilers and settings.  Performance is specific to your application.

Comment: @old_timer Yeah, I was expecting some (hopefully small, < 10%) difference in performance. I was wondering though if maybe there was a change in between 7.4.0 and 9.2.0 where, maybe, 7.4.0 used `nano.specs` by default and now 9.2.0 does not. Or something like that. An obvious change that could be forcing me to set the specs to `nano.specs` now. Otherwise, could I expect a big difference in performance just from the changes posted above? (> 20%). Of course I need to test it, but not sure when I will be able to, so I was looking for a guess/estimation if that was possible at all. :-)

Comment: very possible. also depends on where and how you acquired your toolchain binary.  the prior one may have had a number of settings either default one way or the builder could have set them one way.  And this one could have defaults another way or the builder set them another way.  And that could have been the difference.  The compiler outputs do change over time and not necessarily for the better so some difference is expected, hopefully a few percent but you just have to try it.

Comment: @old_timer Thanks. Post it as an answer. If nobody says otherwise, I will accept yours as the correct answer (i.e.: there is no way to know, but trying). :-D

Comment: @old_timer Would help if you could talk about an experience you had (or someone you know had) where something similar happened: a new binary is about the same size (< 2% diffference), but the performance is now > 20% slower. I would definitely not expect that unless there was a bug in the toolchain. Being GCC widely used and being my project a "toy project", I would say it is unlikely that I found a bug in GCC's code. But of course, my experience is very limited, so I may be completely wrong! :-D

Comment: Point is dont make assumptions you have to test.  Simply adding a nop in the bootstrap can make your code double digits of percent slower, nothing to do with the toolchain.  One could argue if the compiler was perfect then why would we have new versions and second the output from one version to another would be identical.

Comment: gcc is a good generic compiler, there are target specific compilers that do better or at least did until gcc made them obsolete.  clang/llvm should provide tighter/faster code than gcc with the additional optimizations that you cant do in gcc (whole project vs per file only).  but last time I tried it still was falling behind.  I have not tried in a few major revs though.

Comment: benchmarks are BS, it is so easy to manipulate/create a benchmark that exploits a performance feature on one side and/or a problem on another.  add a nop in the bootstrap for certain programs on certain platforms.  Change the order of the objects on the command line when linking, etc.  you have to test your program, with command line options you choose to try, we cant tell you if it is going to be faster or not in general from 7.x.x to 9.x.x, my point is not to assume it will be nor assume it will be slower nor the same.  test it.

Comment: if the program grows or shrinks by a noticable amount even a few percent, what is going on there?  could be a subtle change to the ABI that only affected some functions, or affected all functions in a very small way, etc.  Or it could be the code that was generated, gcc is a good general compiler but I would say not great for any particular one of its targets.  x86 is strong, but if there is a choice does arm win out over x86 when a new feature/fix affects the output of one or both?

Comment: godbolt is a good tool to compare such things, can easiliy bounce between versions, etc for a specific chunk of code to see if the compilers vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do perfectly  understand you want to use the latest and greatest toolchain  from your prefered, mainstream Linux distribution, but this is not always going well.

In my humble opinion, you should:

- stick to [Linaro](https://www.linaro.org/downloads/) or [ARM](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain) gcc toolchains,
- in the case of your specific cortex-m related project, stick to a gcc toolchain more specifically targeting the cortex-m, i.e. the so called '[GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm)'.

Some remarks:

- There are probably excellent reasons why ARM itself is providing two specifics toolchains for the two profiles,
- Latest GCC toolchain version available from Linaro is 7.4.1, but if they used to point to it by default on this [page](https://www.linaro.org/downloads/), they now pointing to version 7.2.1, which may (or not) ring a bell regarding 7.4.1 - there are no official 9.2 versions available yet.
- Latest GCC toolchain available from ARM is 8.3.1 for cortex-m, and 8.3 for cortex-a - there are no official 9.2 versions available yet.

Back to your specific issue now: I was able to compile your project using the following steps:

```
wget "https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/8-2019q3/RC1.1/gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2019-q3-update-linux.tar.bz2?revision=c34d758a-be0c-476e-a2de-af8c6e16a8a2?product=GNU%20Arm%20Embedded%20Toolchain,64-bit,,Linux,8-2019-q3-update" -O gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2019-q3-update-linux.tar.bz2
mkdir -p /opt/arm
tar jxf gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2019-q3-update-linux.tar.bz2 -C /opt/arm
export PATH=/opt/arm/gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2019-q3-update/bin:$PATH
```

Command  `which arm-none-eabi-gcc` should display `/opt/arm/gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2019-q3-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc`.

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/Bulebots/bulebule.git
cd bulebule
scripts/setup_libopencm3.sh
make -s -C src/
```

Command `arm-none-eabi-size ./src/main.elf` should display:

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
55152    3336    7100   65588   10034 ./src/main.elf
```

Please note that there is a Docker file for the latest GCC toolchain from ARM targeting the cortex-m profile [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/stronglytyped/arm-none-eabi-gcc/dockerfile). You may want to use it in your own Docker file and remove those two lines:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc-cs-7.4.0 \
arm-none-eabi-newlib-3.1.0-2.fc30 \
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at Linaro/ARM toolchains and try them out.

Comment: @Peque In the (hypothetical) case you would  be happy with the answer above, please don't forget to accept it - thanks.